# optimizer upgrading a row level lock to a table level lock in a macro

Tags: teradata

What will occur when a row level lock is requested in a macro and the Optimizer determines a
table level lock is required? Will it give a warning while upgrading?

Sorry I don't know how to check it practically by creating such a scenario so I am just asking straight away.

Answer (score 0):

The optimizer determines the neccessary lock when it's optimizing a query.

When you request a row hash lock and there must be a table lock to process the query there will be no warning.

Did you try to **EXPLAIN EXEC mymacro;**?